# Как передать объект из JS файла на html страницу?

Tags: javascript, html, json

У меня возникла несколько сложная проблема, попытаюсь максимально ясно описать. 
Итак, я с сервера получаю два объекта для своих двух моделей. Эти объекты содержат в себе поля категории, фамилии, идентификатор элементов модели и т.п. Путём фильтрации я получаю 4 массива. В первом и втором массиве хранятся уникальные идентификаторы, а в третьем и четвёртом повторяющиеся идентификаторы. В первом массиве содержится уникальный идентификатор для первой модели. во втором - уникальный для второго массива, а в третьем и четвёртом общие элементы для них соответственно.

Для наглядности сказанного приведу следующий пример.

```
const dataFirstModel = [{"revitid": "1"},{"revitid": "2"},{"revitid": "3"},{"revitid": "4"}];
const dataSecondModel = [{"revitid": "1"},{"revitid": "2"},{"revitid": "5"},{"revitid": "6"}];
```

Как видно из кода у них первые две revitid одинаковые, а последние различные. В итоге я путём фильтрации получил следующие массивы:

```
[ //first array(difference)
  { 
    revitid: 3
    building: ""
    level: ""
    room: ""
    viewid: 3302
    category: "Walls"
    family: "Basic Wall"
    symbol: "Wall-Ext_102"
  },{
    revitid: 4
    building: ""
    level: ""
    room: ""
    viewid: 3303
    category: "Walls"
    family: "Basic Wall"
    symbol: "Wall-Ext_102"
  }
];

[ //second array(difference)
  { 
    revitid: 5
    building: ""
    level: ""
    room: ""
    viewid: 3304
    category: "Walls"
    family: "Basic Wall"
    symbol: "Wall-Ext_102"
  },{
    revitid: 6
    building: ""
    level: ""
    room: ""
    viewid: 3305
    category: "Walls"
    family: "Basic Wall"
    symbol: "Wall-Ext_102"
  }
];
[ //first array(similar)
  { 
    revitid: 1
    building: ""
    level: ""
    room: ""
    viewid: 3300
    category: "Walls"
    family: "Basic Wall"
    symbol: "Wall-Ext_102"
  },{
    revitid: 2
    building: ""
    level: ""
    room: ""
    viewid: 3301
    category: "Walls"
    family: "Basic Wall"
    symbol: "Wall-Ext_102"
  }
];

[ //second array(similar)
  { 
    revitid: 1
    building: ""
    level: ""
    room: ""
    viewid: 3300
    category: "Walls"
    family: "Basic Wall"
    symbol: "Wall-Ext_102"
  },{
    revitid: 2
    building: ""
    level: ""
    room: ""
    viewid: 3301
    category: "Walls"
    family: "Basic Wall"
    symbol: "Wall-Ext_102"
  }
];
```

Теперь мне нужно передать эти массивы на html страницу и я не могу справиться с этим заданием.

Передать нужно следующим образом.

1. Кнопка для категорий, которая открывается при нажатии. Категорий может быть несколько, для примера может быть категория стен и крыш.
2. В открытой категории должна быть кнопка для свойства family, которая так же открывается.
3. В открытом family должна быть кнопка для свойства symbol.
4. После нажатия на кнопку со свойством symbol должна открыться список кнопок, по следующим признакам:

   1. В самом верху должна быть кнопка из первого массива, т.е. различия первой модели. Эти кнопки должны иметь фиолетовый цвет фона и метод `onclick="firstModel(${viewid})"`.
   2. Под кнопками из первого массива должны располагаться кнопки второго массива, но они должны иметь зелёный фон и метод `onclick="secondModel(${viewid})"`.
   3. Далее должны следовать кнопки из третьего массива, имеющие оранжевый цвет фона и метод `onclick="firstModel(${viewid})"`.
   4. В конце будут кнопки из четвёртого массива, тоже имеющие оранжевый фон, но с методом `onclick="secondModel(${viewid})"`.

В итоге должен быть такой список:

> category
>
> > family
> >
> > > symbol
> > >
> > > > button
> > > >         button
> > > >         button
> > > >         button
>
> other category
>
> > family
> >
> > > symbol
> > >
> > > > button
> > > >         button

Я буду очень благодарен за помощь. Спасибо за уделенное время, если будут вопросы пожалуйста обращайтесь.

Comment: Если я не правильно понял, поправьте: основная загвоздка в создании `html` структуры через `javascript`?

Comment: Так точно, вы правильно поняли.

Comment: а имеет значение на чистом js или хотя бы jquery?

Comment: Да, на чистом js, если возможно.

Comment: Ещё актуален, буду рад за помощь..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких задач лучше все-го использовать фреймворки которые позволяют делать шаблонизацию, например [VueJs](https://ru.vuejs.org/index.html), особенно если это не единичная задача, а часть более комплексной системы.

Если надо совсем чисто на Js сделать, то в JS есть API для создания DOM динамически.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Пример из документации по ссылке выше:

```
document.body.onload = addElement;

function addElement () { 
  // создаём новый div элемент
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
  // создаём текстовый узел
  var newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!"); 
  // добавляем внутрь
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);  

  // новый элемент будем добавлять в эллемент с id div1
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  // добавляем
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 
}
```

Этот код, это пример как динамически создавать html разметку.
Через этот API можно создавать динамически теги, атрибуты, менять и добавлять в любое место.

```js
const parent = document.getElementById("main");

const data = {
  one: {
    info: "Hello1",
    text: "Text1",
    btn: "Btn1"
  },
  two: {
    info: "Two info",
    text: "Text2",
    btn: "Btn2"
  },
  next: {
    info: "Next info",
    text: "Text3",
    btn: "Btn3"
  }
}

for (const key in data) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("my-class");
  div.innerText = `info: ${data[key].info}, text: ${data[key].text} `;
  const btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.innerText = data[key].btn;
  div.appendChild(btn);
  parent.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
.my-class {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #BFFFA4;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
Some content

<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Я согласен, что чистый js для таких целей не подходит и есть более хорошие решения. Впрочем я не понял, как я могу это применить у себя в коде.

Comment: Пройтись циклом по вашим объектам, в цикле создавать необходимые теги и добавлять в нужное место страницы. Видимо тут будет цикл глубины 3.

Comment: Добавил пример, как по данным из объекта генерировать html разметку.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но вы не могли посмотреть на уже заканчивающееся решение этой проблемы? Вот [код](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-platform-cldd0) почти готового решения, мне остаётся только отобразить всё это на странице. Буду очень благодарен, если вы поможете мне преодолеть этот последний этап.

Comment: @AlisaBondarchuk В вашем коде ошибка в том что функции map нет в id. Функция map это функция массива, а id это не массив, судя по названию.

Comment: Чисто для интереса даю [ссылку](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-cherry-t6pjo) на уже законченный код, вот так в конечном итоге должен выглядеть моя задача. Буду очень рад, если вы предложить улучшение или более хорошее решение.

Comment: @AlisaBondarchuk нормально, если не стоит задача делать код для OpenSource, и оттачивать каждую строчку кода.
А так конечно наверное улучшить можно, не хочется сейчас углубляться в это. Главное что вы принципиально поняли, а тонкости отточите во время практики JS.

Comment: Согласен с вами, спасибо за помощь и поддержку.